# Tag Helpers not properly rendered in ViewComponent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Tag helpers render properly on **ALL** my `razor` pages but not in my `ViewComponents`

For instance:

```
<label asp-for="MiddleName" class="control-label"></label>
```

should render as:

```
<label class="control-label" for="Contact_MiddleName">Middle Name</label>
```

but instead simply is included in the page as is.

I have searched the web high and low for hours but can't find any solution. Any pointers on what to try?

Answer (score 3):

I guess asking the question here gave me an idea.

In my _ViewImports.cshtml file I have

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

which enables tag helpers on all my `razor` `pages`. On a whim I added it to the top of my `ViewComponent.cshtml` and now it works.

I still don't know why I have to add it to each view component file. If someone can give me the answer for that I'll mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Same problem here... Do you have an explanation for this after all?

Comment: Yes, it still seems to be necessary.

Comment: You do not have to add it on all of your razor pages. Check my answer below.

Comment: We weren't adding it to all of our razor pages. The razor pages work fine with having the tag helper import in _ViewImports.cshtml. The problem was needing to add the import to  ViewComponents. Does your answer fix ViewComponents?

Comment: Yes, when you add to _ViewImports the tag that i wrote in my answer everything works properly.  official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @Baskovli that documentation covers "Invoking a view component as a Tag Helper" but it doesn't have details about the problem here which is adding tag helpers to a view component.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add in  _ViewImports.cshtm tag helper with the name of your project.

> @addTagHelper *, ProjectName

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the folder structure of your project.

I guess your project structure is as following:

```
Project Root
   Pages
      _ViewImports.cshtml
   ViewComponents
      ViewComponents.cshtml
```

That means the _ViewImports.cshtml only apply to the Pages Folder, but not the ViewComponents Folder.

Just Move the _ViewImports.cshtml to the root Folder

```
Project Root
   Pages
   ViewComponents
      ViewComponents.cshtml
   _ViewImports.cshtml
```

It should be work now as the _ViewImports.cshtml apply to both Pages and ViewComponents Folder.